# Sort dictionary by specific order (list of keys)

Tags: python

I am trying to sort a dictionary based on the order that its keys appears in a list.

First element of the list would be the first element of the dictionary. At the end the dictionary keys wiould be in the same order as in the provided list...

I can sort by value with this code

```
newlist = sorted(product_list, key=lambda k: k['product'])
```

but cant do it for a list

thanks for any help!

Comment: You can not sort a dictionary.  You can, however, create a new `OrderedDict` from the `collections` module

Comment: @wim is right. If you want to operate on keys and/or values in a specific order, you can loop over a sorted list of its keys by calling `sorted` on `dict.keys()`.

Answer (score 3):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
new_dict = OrderedDict((k, old_dict[k]) for k in key_list)
```

Having said that, there's probably a better way to solve your problem than using an OrderedDict

If some keys are missing, you'll need to use one of

```
new_dict = OrderedDict((k, old_dict.get(k)) for k in key_list)
```

or

```
new_dict = OrderedDict((k, old_dict[k]) for k in key_list if k in old_dict)
```

depending on how you want to handle the missing keys.

Answer (score 2):

In Python (and most languages) [dictionaries are unsorted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array), so you can't "sort" a dictionary.

You can retrieve and sort the keys and iterate through those:

```
for key in sorted(product_list.keys()):
    item = product_list[key]
    item.doSomething()
```

Or you can use a [`OrderDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), like so:

```
 from collections import OrderedDict
```

And then build the dictionary in the required order (which is up to you to determine) but below we sort using the keys:

```
 product_list = OrderDict(sorted(product_list.items(), key=lambda k: k[0]))
```

For reference, `Dict.items()` returns a list of tuples in the form:

```
[(key1, value1), (key2, value2) , ... , (keyN, valueN)]
```

Answer (score 0):

By definition, a dictionary is unordered. You can use `OrderedDict` from `collections` as seen  at http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict as a drop-in replacement.